# Deleting multiple labels in perforce

Tags: perl, perforce, label

I am working on a perforce-perl script that creates labels. Due to repeated execution of the script i have created hundreds of labels of the type LABEL_A.180 etc.
I want to know if there is any command or any other way by which I can delete multiple labels at a time?

Comment: show me your part of script where you use such logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command or feature in P4V to delete multiple labels. The best approach will be just write another script that finds the labels and then removes them one-by-one.

I do not know the P4Perl API so I'm unable to give you an example, however it will be *very similar* to existing label creation just with an [additional `-d` flag](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html) passed to the [`p4 label` command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html).

HTH,

Comment: If you use P4Perl, you can run all your commands in a single server connection, which will greatly improve efficiency.  If you prefer to use the regular command line interface, you should look into the 'p4 -x <file> <cmd>' syntax, which lets you provide inputs from a file or STDIN.

Comment: Yes, thankyou Dennis. I would delete them in a loop by another script.